# How to move to next textbox form a multiline textbox

Tags: c#

I have this procedure wich moves the cursor to the next textbox up/down within non multiline textbox.

When using key down from multiline textbox, cursor moves to the next textbox but does not focus  in the next textbox when pressing key up idem. With key enter it moves from multiline to the next textbox and focuses it.

What can be the reason ?

I have 8 textboxes which are groupped with tag properties from 0 to 7. TxtboxNbrLimit is set to 8

```
    private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            if (KeyIndex < TxtboxNbrLimit)
                ++KeyIndex;
            if (KeyIndex == TxtboxNbrLimit)
            {
                SaveBtn.Select();
                return;
            }
            if (_textBox[KeyIndex].Text != "")
                ChangeDone = true;
            _textBox[KeyIndex].SelectionStart = 0;
            _textBox[KeyIndex].SelectionLength = _textBox[KeyIndex].Text.Length;
            _textBox[KeyIndex].Select();
            _textBox[KeyIndex].Focus(); 
        }
        else
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                if (KeyIndex > 0)
                    --KeyIndex;
               _textBox[KeyIndex].SelectionStart = 0; 
               _textBox[KeyIndex].SelectionLength = _textBox[KeyIndex].Text.Length;
               _textBox[KeyIndex].Select();
               _textBox[KeyIndex].Focus(); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move your logic to key up event instead of key down. That will work fine, **TESTED**.

Maybe multiline TextBox has some kind of event handler internally to handle up/down keyboard key pressed event, to move cursor between text lines. So your code work will be overridden by that internal behavior.

And in case you put it in key up event, the opposite happened. Your code logic will override effect of TextBox's internal behavior. So if the TextBox contains multiline text, the cursor will move to next/previous TextBox instead of moving between text lines inside the multiline TextBox.

Comment: I assumed we are talking about winform (I did the test in winform).

Comment: Yes I am working with WFA in the light of your advice I changed property form keydown to keyup now the cursor pass 2 times by this function and jump to the next without stopping in the multiline textbox. I am playing with other propeties for stopping it in the multiline textbox. I will return to you if it works.

Comment: maybe the method still attached to key down event in addition to key up, so it is executed twice? Just to make sure it isn't.

Comment: I checked it. There is only one property assigned it's KeyUp property pass 2 times. I debugged with F11 it turns two times in this procedure. Now I'am comparing it's properties with other textboxes and test it.

Comment: Finally your advice keyup works. However it pass two times by the procedure but if i assign to the keydown property the cursor does not move to the next textbox. For me it's the answer for the rest I will try to find a solution.

Comment: It's working! Previous and next texboxes had have still keydown property this is why it's passing two times by the procedure. I changed to keyup property only the multiline after your advice. I had to change all.